# Qual a diferença entre Arrays.asList e List.of?

Tags: java, lista, java-9

Estudando o Java 9, vi um novo método que trabalha com coleções: `List.of`, exemplo:

```
List<String> frutas = List.of("maça", "laranja");
```

Já utilizei antes o `Arrays.asList`, exemplo:

```
List<String> frutas = Arrays.asList("maça", "laranja");
```

Qual a diferença entre a utilização destes métodos?

Comment: Segundo a documentação, a primeira retorna uma lista imutável, e a segunda retorna apenas uma lista convertida mutável. Só não sei até onde essa lista é imutável.

Comment: Agora li melhor, Lisf.of retorna uma lista que não pode ter sua estrutura modificada, ou seja, é somente leitura, você não pode adicionar, remover ou substituir nenhum item dela. O Arrays.asList retorna uma lista de tamanho fixo baseado no número de elementos do array correspondente, mas esta lista resultante não é imutável, você pode alterar normalmente sua estrutura.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### `Arrays.asList()`

Retorna uma lista de tamanho fixo suportada pela matriz especificada. Este método atua como ponte entre APIs baseadas em array e baseadas em coleção.

Exemplo:

```
package com.exemplo;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class ArrayExemplo {
  public static void main (String args[]) {

  // cria um array de strings
  String a[] = new String[]{"abc","def","fhi","jkl"};

  List list1 = Arrays.asList(a);

  // imprime a lista
  System.out.println("A lista é:" + list1);
 }
}
```

### `List.of`

A Oracle introduziu alguns métodos convenientes para criar objetos de `List`, `Set`, `Map` e `Map.Entry` imutáveis. Esses métodos de utilidade são usados para **criar objetos de coleção vazios ou não vazios**.

Em Java SE 8 e versões anteriores, podemos usar os métodos de utilidade da classe `Collections`, como o `unmodifiableXXX` para criar objetos `Collection` Imutáveis. Por exemplo, se queremos criar um List Imutável, podemos usar o método `Collections.unmodifiableList`.

No entanto, estes métodos `Collections.modifiableXXX` são **muito tediosos e verbosos**. Para superar essas falhas, a Oracle adicionou alguns métodos de utilidade às interfaces `List`, `Set` e `Map`.

As interfaces `List` e `Set` possuem métodos "`of()`" para criar um `List` ou `Set` imutáveis vazio ou não vazio como mostrado abaixo:

```
List umListImutavelVazio = List.of();
```

`List` não vazio:

```
List umListImutavel = List.of("um","dois","tres");
```

Answer (score 3):

Complementando a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/244278/112052), há várias diferenças entre esses dois métodos ([referência](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46579074)).

Uma já foi citada: [`Arrays.asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) retorna uma lista que pode ser modificada (mas com ressalvas, veja logo abaixo), enquanto [`List.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#of(E...)) retorna uma lista que **não** pode ser modificada:

```
// esta lista pode ser modificada (posso mudar elementos já existentes)
List<String> asList = Arrays.asList("maça", "laranja");
// mudando o elemento da posição zero
asList.set(0, "abacaxi"); // OK
System.out.println(asList); // [abacaxi, laranja]

// esta lista não pode ser modificada
List<String> listOf = List.of("maça", "laranja");
listOf.set(0, "abacaxi"); // Erro: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

Porém, vale lembrar de um detalhe: a lista retornada por `Arrays.asList` tem tamanho fixo, ou seja, **eu só consigo mudar os valores das posições já existentes** (como fiz acima com o método `set`). Mas se eu quiser adicionar ou remover elementos, dará erro:

```
List<String> asList = Arrays.asList("maça", "laranja");
// qualquer método que mude o tamanho da lista dá erro
asList.add("banana"); // Erro: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
asList.remove(0); // Erro: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

---

Outra diferença é o tratamento dado para valores nulos. `Arrays.asList` aceita elementos nulos, enquanto `List.of` não:

```
// ok, pode ter null
List<String> asList = Arrays.asList("maça", "laranja", null);
System.out.println(asList); // [abacaxi, laranja, null]

// erro, não pode ter null
List<String> listOf = List.of("maça", "laranja", null); // NullPointerException
```

O mesmo ocorre quando vou verificar se há um elemento nulo:

```
List<String> asList = Arrays.asList("maça", "laranja");
// pode verificar se contém elemento nulo
System.out.println(asList.contains(null)); // false

List<String> listOf = List.of("maça", "laranja");
// não pode verificar se contém elemento nulo
System.out.println(listOf.contains(null)); // NullPointerException
```

---

Outra diferença é que, quando passamos um array para estes métodos, `Arrays.asList` mantém uma referência para o array original, e portanto alterações em um refletem no outro. Já com `List.of` isso não acontece, e alterações em um não refletem no outro:

```
String[] frutas = { "maça", "laranja" };
List<String> asList = Arrays.asList(frutas);
System.out.println(asList); // [maça, laranja]

// modificações no array refletem na lista
frutas[0] = "abacaxi";
System.out.println(asList); // [abacaxi, laranja]
// modificações na lista refletem no array
asList.set(1, "banana");
System.out.println(frutas[1]); // banana


//-------------------------------------------
String[] frutas2 = { "maça", "laranja" };
List<String> listOf = List.of(frutas2);
System.out.println(listOf); // [maça, laranja]

// modificações no array NÃO refletem na lista
frutas2[0] = "abacaxi";
System.out.println(listOf); // [maça, laranja]
```

---

Por fim, vale mencionar também [`Collections.unmodifiableList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList(java.util.List)), que assim como `List.of`, retorna uma lista que não pode ser modificada (`set`, `add` e `remove` lançam `UnsupportedOperationException`), mas a diferença é que `unmodifiableList` aceita valores nulos.