# É possível colocar objetos em uma ArrayList logo que instanciada?

Tags: java, lista, arraylist

A dúvida se aplica não só em um `ArrayList`, mas em qualquer tipo de `List`. Pois é possível adicionar objetos na `ArrayList` logo depois instanciarmos ela, e sem precisar usar o método `add()`? Tal qual pode ser feito com *arrays*?

**Exemplo do que eu quero fazer, só que usando um *array*, ao invés de um *collection*:**

```
int[5] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

Comment: Relacionada: [Qual a diferença entre `Arrays.asList` e `List.of`?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/243874/4808)

Comment: Renan, obrigado pela adição ao post, não tinha conhecimento desses métodos, certamente vão me ajudar a chegar na solução que eu preciso para o problema relacionado à pergunta.

Comment: Mas você sabe me dizer se os métodos dessa pergunta que mencionaste estão disponíveis no Java 8? Ou é apenas Java 9 mesmo?

Comment: `List.of ` está presente somente no Java 9. `Arrays.asList` já existe há mais tempo: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não é possível em Java.

É possível [inicializar o *array* com um tamanho específico](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#%3Cinit%3E(int)) para evitar que precise realocações quando a lista fica maior que o *array* disponível.

As opções citadas em [resposta *linkada* em comentário acima e outras respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/243874/4808) aqui não geram uma lista real, gera algo que se parece uma lista, mas ela fica imutável e não pode fazer tudo o que se espera de uma lista. E não é algo eficiente, é só um facilitador.

Se isto serve, então um *array* resolve seu problema e ele pode ser inicializado como deseja. Portando as outras soluções ou não resolvem o problema citado ou o problema pode ser resolvido de forma muito mais elegante e performática.

É possível criar um método que crie uma lista real a partir de uma sequência de argumentos, mas também não é eficiente. Na verdade é muito ineficiente porque haverá duas cópias, uma para inicializar o *array* que será passado para o método e outra para copiar para a lista.

Em C# tem como fazer isso, mas é só açúcar sintático. Em C++ tem como fazer, em certas circunstâncias de forma eficiente.

Comment: Obrigado pelo exclarecimento.

Comment: Não sei se a resposta está correta, você viu [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/243874/4808) Maniero?

Comment: @Renan tecnicamente está correta, eu melhorei para mostrar porque.

Comment: O caso apresentado na resposta linkada no comentário acima me serviria, porque eu quero criar essa list apenas para informar como argumento a um método que irá salvar todos os objetos presentes na List em um banco de dados, não irá modificar a List de maneira nenhuma, então a pergunta linkada me ajudaria a chegar na solução. Porém, eu não posso usar o Java 9 no projeto. A resposta do Maniero é até então a mais adequada. Obrigado ao Renan por ter apresentado o método List.of à discussão, irá ajudar a quem tiver esse problema no futuro, e obrigado ao Maniero pelos exlacrecimentos.

Comment: @Brunno veja no [tour] a melhor forma de dizer obrigado.

Comment: @Maniero Obrigado por lembrar. Eu já utilizava o Stack Overflow antes, conheço a função de aceitar a resposta, só que geralmente esqueço de marcar porque tem aquele tempo de espera mínimo.

Comment: @Brunno vc pode votar em tudo tb.

Answer (score 7):

Se quiser uma lista mutável simples, nada te impede de fazer isso:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class MinhasListas {
    public static <E> List<E> of(E... elementos) {
        return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(elementos));
    }
}
```

Um exemplo de uso seria assim:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> x = MinhasListas.of("a", "b", "c");
        List<Integer> y = MinhasListas.of(1, 2, 3);
    }
}
```

E isso daí funciona com qualquer versão do Java do 5 para cima. Então, mesmo se você estiver preso em uma versão antiga, não terá problemas.

Comment: Muito obrigado, eu tava querendo criar um método pra suprir a falta do of, já que uso Java 8. Isso serve com certeza!

Answer (score 5):

A partir do Java 9, você tem [métodos estáticos na interface `List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#immutable) para isso:

```
List<String> abc = List.of("a", "b", "c");
```

Porém a utilização desse método cria uma lista que será imutável, e não poderá ser feito tudo o que é possível fazer com uma lista "normal".